# Stability of fixed points $ \begin{cases} \dot x= \frac{r}{y-d}+y -x\\ \dot y = a+bx-y. \end{cases} $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, fixed-points

We have the set of nonlinear equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot x= \frac{r}{y-d}+y -x\\
\dot y = a+bx-y.
\end{cases}
$$
where parameters $r$, $d$, $a$, $b$ are real. There are two fixed points. If I had an autonomous system, I would evaluate the Jacobian in these fixed points in order to determine their stability. But this system is non-autonomous because $a$, and now I can't go on.

Some help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see why the presence of $a$ makes the system non-autonomous; it looks autonomous to me.  Am I missing something?

Comment: In mathematics, an autonomous system or autonomous differential equation is a system of ordinary differential equations which does not explicitly depend on the independent variable.

Comment: As I understand $a$ is not the independent variable but a parameter so your system is autonomous.

Comment: I'm sorry. Then I didn't understand the meaning of autonomous system! Thanks

Comment: This system has ugly critical points and also has bifurcations.

Comment: @Moo, bifurcations? I didn't imagine it. Could you add some details in an answer please? It is interesting